# How can i get rank or position base highest ' gpa' and 'total' into database rows data in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter-3

How can i get rank or position base highest ' gpa' and 'total' into database rows data in   codeigniter?

```
public function fetchData() {
    $data = array();
    $data['fetch_data'] = $this->excel_data_insert_model->fetch_data();
    $result = $data['fetch_data']->result();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        //echo $row.'<br/>';
        $id = $row->id;
        $p_student_id = $row->stu_id;
        $p_section = $row->section;
        $p_gpa = $row->gpa;
        $p_total = $row->total;
        $x = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your raw query like SELECT * from tablename so that it can be helpful to convert it into ci

Comment: model  public function fetch_data()
 {
  $query=$this->db->select('*')->order_by('gpa,total','desc')->get('tbl_v1');
  return $query;
 }

Answer (score 1):

My Answer to your raw query could be this:

```
Select column_name1, column_name2, MAX(gpa),MAX(total) from tbl_v1 ORDER by gpa, total desc
```

Also for CI

```
$query=$this->db->select('column_name1, column_name2, MAX(gpa),MAX(total)')->order_by('gpa,total','desc'‌​)->get('tbl_v1'); 
return $query;
```

Comment: how  to get all students rank? in view. if  any student got highest mark but gpa o.00 that student will not rank or position

Comment: Just pass this array to a view using $this->load->view('page_name',$array_of_result);